# jquery time validation

Tags: jquery, validation, time

I was hoping to write a function that validated the time format of the text field that it is attached to in the 12H format

```
HH:MM AM|PM
```

Nothing to fancy.  Just something that turns the text field red or something.  I don't want it to even keep the form from submitting.  I just want it show the user that he is an idiot for entering in the wrong time.  I already have a regular expression in mind

```
(1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)
```

My only problem I guess Is the jQuery format.  After all this time, while I have become familiar with jQuery syntax, I am still not that comfortable programming in it all together.  I am going to attempt to get this done myself but if you guys already have a tidy solution, there is no point in reinventing the wheel.  Let me know what you guys think.

Here is what I had so far... Testing it out so far... Thinking about using jquery validation despite my previous protestations

```
$('#DischargeDateTimeMask').blur(function () {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var dateReg = /^(1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i) (am|pm)$/
        if (!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-4">Incorrect time format fool!: HH:mm am|pm</span>');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you want to know? You can use that regular expression in your form submit and see if it matches the value of the field like so:

```
var myregex = new RegExp("");
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    if(!$("#mydateinput").val().match(/(1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)/)) {
        // Do stuff to show things about things being invalid.
        return false;
    }
});
```

But what is the real point? :)

Comment: I guess I am just trying to practice writing some jquery.  What I have currently uses the $.blur event to key the comparison...  I was initially trying to avoid jquery Validation, because I do want this submit if the user doesn't enter a value in the time field (this is not required) and I don't know how to use regexes with Validation, but I have been rethinking that over the last couple of minutes... I will update my post with what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is about what I am looking for...

```
$('#DischargeDateTimeMask').blur(function () {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var dateReg = /^(1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)? (am|pm)+$/;
    if (!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
        $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-4">Incorrect time format fool!: HH:mm am|pm</span>');
    }
    //alert(dateReg.test(inputVal));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a code for check whether start time is grater than end time

to check 10:00:00 < 12:00:00 in this time format

// start time=10:00:00

// end time=12:00:00

//------code Jquery -------

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $.validator.addMethod("graterThan", function(value, element,date) {
            //If false, the validation fails and the message below is displayed

            var st= $(date).val();
            var etime=parseInt(value.replace(/:/g,""),10);
            var stime=parseInt(st.replace(/:/g,""),10);
            return etime>stime;
        }, "End time must be larger than start time");
```

//---- how to call -------

```
        $().ready(function() {

            $("#AllocationForm").validate({
                rules : { endTime:{graterThan:"#startTime"}}
            });

        });

    </script>
```